# How to recursive run DIR command without using /S switch

Tags: cmd

I have the following folders and files:

```
C:\Test\file.txt
C:\Test\Folder\file.txt
```

I am working on a Java program which looks for a specific folder and run DIR command on it. The folder is passed as a parameter and the results are saved in a file:

```
   cmd /c dir "C:\Test" /s /b /a-D > c:\Test\DIR.txt
```

However, sometimes I do not have a folder as a parameter and I just have a file; my command will be:

```
   cmd /c dir "C:\Test\file.txt" /s /b /a-D > c:\Test\DIR.txt
```

The results is:

```
   C:\Test\file.txt
   C:\Test\Folder\file.txt
```

When the parameter is a file, I just want that particular file to be listed (no recursivity). So, if I have:

```
   cmd /c dir "C:\Test\file.txt" /s /b /a-D > c:\Test\DIR.txt
```

I want the result to be:

```
   C:\Test\file.txt
```

How can I do this? Eliminating /S switch will work incorrectly if I have a folder as parameter.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If the file exists, then use that name. Otherwise, run the `dir` command with the `/s` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Add a backslash to end and test if it is a valid folder:

```
cmd /c (if exist "somePath\" (dir "somePath" /s /b /a-d) else dir "somePath" /b /a-d) >c:\Test\DIR.txt
```

Option 2: Assume it is a file, suppressing error message, and conditionally do recursive DIR if first command failed:

```
cmd /c (dir /b /a-d "somePath" 2>nul || dir /b /a-d /s "somePath") >c:\Test\DIR.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you include a check in the Java code to see if the directory/folder exists before the call to cmd is made? I don't know Java syntax for that kind of thing, but in C# I'd use something like:

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Test"))
{
    // start the cmd process with the folder you're after including the /S switch
}
else
{
    // The directory won't exist if it's a file, so run it without the /S parameter
}
```

Of course, it depends on what how your program will work for if you can implement that kind of check or not. But it's an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

IsDirectory.bat

```
@Echo off
pushd %1 >nul 2>&1  
If errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 Echo %~nx1 is a folder
If errorlevel 1 Echo %~nx1 is not a folder
Popd

If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause


pause
```